# KL divergence for time-series prediction

Tags: keras, time-series

I am training a model to predict time series data. I would like the residuals of the model to be approximately normally distributed, as this is convenient for making probabilistic statements.

The model I'm considering works as follows, with `i/o` scaled to into the same range:

```
               Batch of observations ↴
Batch of inputs ⟶ Batch of outputs ⟶ Batch of residuals ⟶ Bins
```

The model is then trained using KL divergence so that the bins approximate a (discrete) normal distribution on the batch.

What I'm having trouble with is the binning part. I need a layer where the activation of each node is roughly the proportion of samples in the batch that are in each bin. That is to say, if there are `100` samples in the batch and `15` of them result in a residual between `-0.1` and `0.1`, then the activation of the the "`[-0.1,0.1]` neuron" should be close to `0.15`.